Call a Class-function only once on variable change
I am trying to call a function every time a variable in my object is changed. If multiple values are changed, I still want the function to be called only once, after all values are updated.
I tried to do this by overwriting the __setattr__ attribute of my class, like this:
class Test:
    def __init__(self, length: int = 0, data: list = []):
        self.data = data
        self.length = length

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
        print(f"Variable {key} changed to {value}!")
        self.somecoolfunction()

obj = Test(length=5, data=[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
obj.length, obj.data = 10, [1, 1, 1]

The problem is, somecoolfunction() is called twice (for every variable) during initialization, and also twice, when I change the variables, leading to this output:
Variable data changed  to [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]!
Variable length changed  to 5!
Variable length changed  to 10!
Variable data changed  to [1, 1, 1]!

It doesnt make any sense to do all calculations in somecoolfunction() when not all variables are changed yet. Ideally, the function is only called once, after all changes are finished.
I could of cource do this by introducing a new update() function:
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
        print(f"Variable {key} changed to {value}!")
    self.somecoolfunction()

I find this to be counter-intutitive though. Doing it this way, the IDE doesnt show me what variables I can change. And a lot of users will straight up try to assign the variables directly and skip the function. How would you go about this? Thanks!


Use a function which can explicitly set multiple values at once. That won't be able to use the simple foo.bar = baz syntax. 2) Explicitly call a function to calculate the values when needed. 3) Set an internal flag anytime you alter values, like self._changed = True. Create a function which calculates and returns the value, maybe make that a @property. Use the self._changed flag as indicator whether you need to recalculate or whether the last calculated value should still be good.


How do you know "when all variables are changed", i.e. what are the rules here? How do you expect the object to know that everything is changed? For example, change data, change lenght (then run your cool function), add (list append) to data (or only run now your function)? And What happens when data changes, data changes, data changes, length changes. Does the function only execute when both data and length is changed at least once?

Ah yes,adding a flag might  indeed work. I can make a flag, use __setattr__ to set it and check it every time the user e.g. requests the result. If the flag is set, recalculate, if not, give the previous value. Great! Thanks!

The update approach is a good idea. Problem with users skipping it can be easily solved using properties:
class Test:
    def __init__(self, length: int = 0, data: Optional[list] = None):
        if data is None:
            self._data = []
        else:
            self._data = data
        self._length = length

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
    
    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

Now trying to set length and data values directly will result in an exception, since there is no setter for it:
obj.length = 5 # AttributeError: property 'length' of 'Test' object has no setter

update method can easily be adapted to get around that:
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, f"_{key}", value)
            print(f"Variable {key} changed to {value}!")
        self.somecoolfunction()

It now refers to private values directly, so it doesn't need setter for properties.
obj = Test(length=5, data=[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]) # Nothing is printed on initalisation,
                                              # since you set private values directly.
obj.update(length = 10, data = [1, 1, 1])     # prints changed message for both attributes

Side note 1:
Of course that can still be bypassed by setting obj._length = 5, but marking an attribute as private by naming it starting with _ is usually enough to tell someone: "this is private, you probably shouldn't touch it"
Side note 2:
Don't use mutable default arguments, like you did with data: list = [] - "Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument

This is eactly what I was looking for! Making them privateis of course the easiest approach.  Thanks!
